# Delta-Epsilon why is delta*c less than or equal to eplison*c

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

In a delta-epsilon proof, you find a delta that you set to epsilon. This delta is less than or equal to epsilon. Why is this? I understand that in a limit delta can shrink arbitrarily until a value as close to 0 (the distance to a) as possible but how is it that delta is less than epsilon?

Comment: Your question is very vague, if you refer to a specific instance of the problem we might point you to the right direction there. In general, the idea of the epsilon delta proofs is that for EVERY epsilon we can find a delta such that the function value is close to the limit. This means that we just have to find a single delta that satisfies our requirements. Choosing delta to depend on epsilon in some way is an easy way of showing this for an arbitrary epsilon.

Comment: Very often, you solve these problems by looking at what $\varepsilon$ needs to do and then working backwards to what $\delta$ needs to do.

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen the formula $\delta \leq \epsilon$ in a delta-epsilon proof. There are even limits you can solve with delta-epsilon proofs in which you set $\delta = 2\epsilon$. If you copy a specific proof from somewhere, starting at the beginning and including everything up to at least the step where you first saw a confusing statement about $\delta$, someone might be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit ordering for $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ in an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof. The concept to understand, is that $\epsilon$ is a fixed value greater than $0$, and $\delta(\epsilon)$ such that continuity occurs.

For simplicity, consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Defining point continuity:

> A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is *continuous* at a point $x^*\in\mathbb{R}$, if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta(\epsilon) > 0$ such that, for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$,
>    $$\|x - x^*\| < \delta \Rightarrow \|f(x) - f(x^*)\| < \epsilon.$$

So, $\delta$ is just a positive value dependent on $\epsilon$, but there's no required ordering between $\delta$ and $\epsilon$.

Consider Lipschitz continuity of $f$, which implies continuity. For any $\epsilon > 0$, we can define $\delta(\epsilon) = \Lambda \epsilon$ and continuity of $f$ would hold, where $\Lambda\in\mathbb{R}_+$ is the Lipschitz constant. So with this, we can see that for $\Lambda \geq 1$, we could define $\delta$ such that $\delta \geq \epsilon$. But it isn't necessary to make it that large, as we just need existence.